# What makes an algebra finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What makes an arbitrary algebra finite?

If an algebra $A$ is generated by an infinite set of generators, but the operations of $A$ are finitary, is $A$ finite or infinite?

If $A$ is generated by a finite set of generators, but the operations on $A$ are infinitary, is $A$ finite or infinite?

In other words, what does really determine the cardinality of an algebra?

Comment: What do you mean by "finitary operation?"

Comment: They likely meant an operation which takes a finite number of inputs.  That is, a function $f:A^n\to A$ on an underlying set $A$ for some $n<\infty$.

Comment: Can you explain which concept of algebra you are referring to here?

Answer (score 2):

Whether the operations are finitary or infinitary, it is not possible to determine whether an algebra is finite knowing only whether or not it is finitely generated.

In general, it may not even be possible to determine whether an algebra is finite given any amount of information. For finitely generated groups, which have finitary operations, given a set of relations there is no terminating algorithm that correctly determines whether the group is finite. That means it is impossible to answer your third question. However, finite algebras with infinitary operations do exist. For example, you can send $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)\mapsto a_1$. This isn't a particularly interesting operation, but it is infinitary, and it can be defined on any set, including finite sets.

Your second question, however, has an easy answer: if the algebra is generated by infinitely many distinct elements, then it cannot possibly be finite, for in particular the infinitely many generators comprise an infinite subset.